# Missing function body

Tags: function, go

When I saw `math.Sin` in Golang , I wondered because it was two functions with same names but first function have not function body.
See below :

For example `math.Acos` :

```
// Acos returns the arccosine, in radians, of x.
//
// Special case is:
//  Acos(x) = NaN if x < -1 or x > 1
func Acos(x float64) float64

func acos(x float64) float64 {
    return Pi/2 - Asin(x)
}
```

But when I want to create a very very simple `uuid` package with below statements :

```
package uuid

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "fmt"
    "io"
)

// Generate generates a random UUID according to RFC 4122
func Generate() (string, error)

func generate() (string, error) {
    uuid := make([]byte, 16)
    n, err := io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, uuid)
    if n != len(uuid) || err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    uuid[8] = uuid[8]&^0xc0 | 0x80
    uuid[6] = uuid[6]&^0xf0 | 0x40
    return fmt.Sprintf("%x-%x-%x-%x-%x", uuid[0:4], uuid[4:6], uuid[6:8], uuid[8:10], uuid[10:]), nil
}
```

I've got an error that said `missing function body for "Generate"`

So how can I write functions like `math.Acos` ?

Comment: I found that if your function has multi return value, and you don't use bracket wrap, such as `func Somefunc(test input) string, error` you will get this error, after you use bracket wrap `func Somefunc(test input) (string, error)` the error disappear.

Answer (score 3):

`acos` and `Acos` are different functions, with differing implementations.  The same with your `Generate()` and `generate()`.

The `acos` method is implemented in assembly, and this is just the method prototype.  You do not need to pre-declare your UUID generation function, as the compiler is multi-pass.